# Problem in sending values between pages in PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to send data from one page to the other via a form in PHP. In the initial page I have included the following PHP script that generates an input form with hidden fields. The names of these hidden fields are generated by the PHP:

```
<?php
  echo     "<form class='available-form' name='available_os' method='get' action='process-results.php'>";
  echo        "<input type='hidden' name='$software'></input>";
  echo        "<input type='hidden' name='$version'></input>";
  echo        "<input type='submit' name='available-button' value='Find Available Libraries for this Software'></input>";
  echo     "</form>";
?>
```

In the second page, named *process-results.php*, I would like to get the names of these hidden fields via the $_GET method but of course using $_GET[$software] and $_GET[$version] wouldn't work...Can someone tell me if there is a solution to this issue or if there is a better alternative? Thanks in advance

Comment: stop echoing html before it's too late

Comment: BTW, you should use double quotes for html attributes, that's the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
"<input type='hidden' name='$software'></input>";
```

you should use

```
"<input type='hidden' name='software' value='".$software."'></input>";
```

for each. This way, you can use `$_GET['software']` to retrieve the value. Do this for each of your hidden inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want something like:

```
<form ... >
    <input type="hidden" name="software" value="<?php echo $software ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="version" value="<?php echo $version ?>" />
</form>
```

and then

```
$_GET['software'];
$_GET['version'];
```

Comment: Doh! Didn't even realize I did that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but this looks odd to me.  Isn't the below code more of what you're looking for?

```
<?php
  echo     "<form class='available-form' name='available_os' method='get' action='process-results.php'>";
  echo        "<input type='hidden' name='software' value='$software'></input>";
  echo        "<input type='hidden' name='version' value='$version'></input>";
  echo        "<input type='submit' name='available-button' value='Find Available Libraries for this Software'></input>";
  echo     "</form>";
?>
```

That way you will get a query string in form of `?software=yoursoftwarename&version=yourversion` and it will be available via `$_GET["software"]` and `$_GET["version"]` on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over each of the items in the `$_GET` array on process-results.php. The problem is that the keys for the value will be whatever $software and $version are set to on the first page. Try something like this:

```
foreach($_GET as $key=>$string) {
 // Do stuff with them
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to have the dollar-sign inside the name, escape it:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='\$software'>";
```

or put the string in single-quotes:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="$software">';
```

Otherwise PHP is looking for a variable named "$software", if you look inside the browser-source you will see that the name-attributes are empty(except you're having those variables defined somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

To the  tag... so it looks like

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method......
```